# Rotational invariance assumed, what is the number of $r$-sided simple polygons that can be inscribed into an $n$-sided regular polygon?

Tags: co.combinatorics, group-actions, enumerative-combinatorics, polygons, enumerative-geometry

When I say that an $r$-sided simple (*i.e.*, not self-intersecting) polygon is inscribed into an $n$-sided regular polygon, I mean that every vertex of the simple $r$-gon is also a vertex of the regular $n$-gon. Let $M(r,n)$ stand for the number of different simple $r$-gons that can be inscribed into a regular $n$-gon. *What is the formula for $M(r,n)$?* I assume that, if $P$ and $Q$ are two $r$-sided simple polygons, and $Q$ can be obtained from $P$ by means of a rotation, then $P=Q$. (Without this assumption, $M(r,n)$ would obviously be equal to ${n \choose r}$.)

I solved some small cases with *Maple*, obtaining results like $M(4,6)=3$, $M(5,7)=3$ and $M(7,12)=66$. These results suggest that, if $r$ and $n$ are relatively prime (their gcd is $1$), then $M(r,n)=\frac{1}{n}{n \choose r}$. Is this hypothesis true? And what is the formula for $M(r,n)$ in the case $gcd(r,n)>1$? For $r=4$ and $n=6$, the formula $M(r,n)=\frac{1}{n}{n \choose r}$ gives the result $\frac{1}{6}\cdot 15=\frac{5}{2}$, which is of course wrong. The result $M(4,6)=3$ can be seen even without Maple. Suppose that, during a counterclockwise tour, the vertices of the regular hexagon appear in the order $A$, $B$, $C$, $D$, $E$, $F$. Then the three inscribable quadrilaterals are $ADEF$, $ACEF$ and $ACDF$.

Comment: I think you should rather ask, given an n and r, what is the number of r-gons which are invariant under rotation of $2pi k/n$? If you know the answer to this, then you can use inclusion-exclusion / möbius inversion to easily compute  the answer of your original question. Now, an answer for my suggested question should be relatively simple (and might already have been solved in the context of 'cyclic sieving' by Reiner-Stanton-White)

Comment: Perhaps this problem is also related to Burnside's lemma. My hope is that this problem has already been solved (at least partially), and that here I shall get a reference to the solution. Incidentally, the original author of this question is Zoran Šćekić, a musician and composer, who asked me for help (because I am a mathematician), and I am now asking the community for help. If I understand it correctly, if in an octave there were a total of $n$ tones and half-tones, then there would be $M(r,n)$ musical scales of length $r$.

Comment: The number $M(r,n)$ is most easily found in the case $gcd(r,n)=1$. It seems that $gcd(r,n)=1 \Rightarrow M(r,n)=\frac{1}{n}{n \choose r}$. Next I shall try to solve (by the method suggested by @PerAlexandersson) the case when $r$ and $n$ have two common divisors: the number  $1$ and a prime number $p>1$. Then I shall probably stop. When musical scales become hard to count, it is not indispensable to count them.

Comment: Surely the answer to @PerAlexandersson's question is just $\binom{n/k}{r/k}$?

Comment: And indeed, [OEIS A047996](http://oeis.org/A047996) confirms that PET applied to $\binom{n/k}{r/k}$ gives the result.

Comment: I think that, when $r$ and $n$ have two common divisors, $1$ and $p$, the formula for $M(r,n)$ reads $M(r,n)=\frac{1}{n}{n \choose r}+\frac{p-1}{n}{n/p \choose r/p}$. I shall not try to write a proof, but shall try to gather some numerical evidence. For example, the formula gives $M(6,15)=\frac{1}{15}{15 \choose 6}+\frac{2}{15}{5 \choose 2}=\frac{5005}{15}+\frac{20}{15}=\frac{5025}{15}=335$, and I shall check with Maple whether $M(6,15)$ is really $335$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$M(r, n) = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{d \,\mid\, \gcd(r,n)} \varphi(d) \binom{n/d}{r/d}$$
See [OEIS A047996](http://oeis.org/A047996) for references.

Comment: Thank you for this excellent answer! If $r$ and $n$ have just two common divisors, $1$ and $p>1$, then $p$ is a prime number. The formula $M(r, n) = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{d \,\mid\, \gcd(r,n)} \varphi(d) \binom{n/d}{r/d}$ then becomes $M(r,n)=\frac{1}{n} \sum_{d \,\mid\, p} \varphi(d) \binom{n/d}{r/d} = \frac{1}{n} [1 \cdot {n \choose r} + (p-1) \cdot {n/p \choose r/p}] = \frac{1}{n}{n \choose r} + \frac{p-1}{n}{n/p \choose r/p}$.

Comment: By the way, before @PeterTaylor wrote the general solution, I tested the formula $M(r,n)= \frac{1}{n}{n \choose r} + \frac{p-1}{n}{n/p \choose r/p}$ five times. The formula produces, and direct enumeration confirms, the following results: $M(4,6)=3$, $M(7,14)=246$, $M(6,15)=335$, $M(10,15)=201$, and $M(8,18)=2438$.